# Removing a <span> in a <div>

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="weeks"> 
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
<span>9</span>
<span>10</span>
</div>
```

I want to be able to call a JavaScript function that will remove the first `<span>` whenever I call it (so the first time I call it, it'll remove the `<span>` with 1 in it, the next time 2, etc.), what's the best way to go about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Use this function:

```
function removeFirst(selector){
   $(selector).children().first().remove();
}
```

So it takes the jquery selector as a parameter. Use it like this:

```
removeFirst('#weeks');
```

That will remove the first child every time you call it.

Answer (score 2):

In plain JavaScript you could do:

```
var weeks = document.getElementById("weeks");
weeks.removeChild(weeks.firstElementChild);
```

[JsFiddle Complete Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MveRf/)